# Objects are being recreated in Android Dependency Injection with Dagger/Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use the **same object** in **two ViewModels**, but the object is **being recreated** each time.

***Question***. Am I doing something wrong, or is it supposed to happen?

> ⬇️⬇️⬇️ Here are my Classes. please look into it. Thanks for helping..

`AppModule.kt`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideModsLoader(): ModsLoader {
        return ModsLoader()
    }
}
```

`FirstViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class FirstViewModel @Inject constructor(
     modsLoader: ModsLoader
) : ViewModel() {
     ...
     here I adding value to my ModsLoader object's mutableList
}
```

`SecondViewModel.kt`

```
@HiltViewModel
class SecondViewModel @Inject constructor(
    modsLoader: ModsLoader,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
    here I am using that property modified in the last view model
    *** But I am getting empty list ***
}
```

`ModLoader.kt`

```
class ModsLoader {
    val modsByCategories = mutableListOf<ModsByCategory>()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Annotate your provider method with `@Singleton`.

Comment: Should I add it to each dependency?